# Publish on Google Apps Marketplace and "Requesting permission to access your Google Account"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish an application on Google Apps Marketplace.
The tester  wrote me, to inform me about "Requesting permission to access your Google Account", because shouldn't  display this screen:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwB9OJxm-hSjZVhVZTdsVFVYRjA/edit?usp=sharing

I need a functionality like the the https://www.gqueues.com/ app Sign in.
I've developed the app with Google App Engine and Java. But I do not know how can I change this functionality.
What steps would you take to reach the required functionality?

Thank you very much in advance and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

This questions the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915001/how-to-use-oauth2-openid-connect-with-userservice). The App Engine User Service uses OpenID and therefore cannot be used with a Google Apps Marketplace listing. See the other question for details on how to work around it.